ASP.NET Core API: Handling 404 Errors for Endpoints
I'm developing an ASP.NET Core API and facing an issue where the request to the api endpoint (/api/plants/search) consistently returns a 404 error, despite seemingly correct controller and routing configurations.
Why might my API endpoint consistently return a 404 error despite the correct routing setup shown below? Can anyone identify any misconfigurations in the provided code that could lead to a 404 error for the /api/plants/search endpoint?

When deploying it locally in my developing environment, all works fine. So, I guess the controllers are actually setup correctly.
I verified, that my API is actually up and running and it is. It has access to the database.
Checked the order of middleware to ensure UseCors, UseAuthentication, UseAuthorization, and endpoint routing are configured correctly.
Ensured app.MapControllers(); is called in the Program.cs.
Initially had app.MapFallbackToController("Index", "Fallback"); but commented it out to avoid interference with API routes.
Checked my IIS configuration and disabled default documents.

This is the code of my Program.cs:
using API;
using API.Data;
using API.Extensions;
using API.Middleware;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddApplicationServices(builder.Configuration);
builder.Services.AddIdentityServices(builder.Configuration);
builder.Logging.AddConsole();

var connString = "";
connString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(opt =>
{
    opt.UseSqlServer(connString);
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
app.UseMiddleware<ExceptionMiddleware>();

app.UseCors("AllowSpecificOrigin");
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

// app.UseDefaultFiles();
// app.UseStaticFiles();

app.MapControllers();
// app.MapFallbackToController("Index", "Fallback");

using var scope = app.Services.CreateScope();
var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
try 
{
    var context = services.GetRequiredService<DataContext>();
    await context.Database.MigrateAsync();
    await Seed.SeedAdmin(context);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    var logger = services.GetService<ILogger<Program>>();
    logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred during migration");
}

app.Run();

This is the content of my appsettings.json (I removed the connection string and the token key for security reasons):
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "CONNECTION STRING"
  },
  "TokenKey": "TOKEN KEY"
}


The content of my ApplicationServiceExtensions.cs:
using API.Data;
using API.Interfaces;
using API.Services;

namespace API.Extensions
{
    public static class ApplicationServiceExtensions
    {
        public static IServiceCollection AddApplicationServices(this IServiceCollection services, 
            IConfiguration config)
        {
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("AllowSpecificOrigin",
                    builder => builder.WithOrigins(
                        "https://localhost:4200",
                        "https://plantguide.ch",
                        "https://www.plantguide.ch",
                        "https://edgarsplantguide.com",
                        "https://www.edgarsplantguide.com"
                    )
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowAnyMethod());   
            });
            services.AddScoped<ITokenService, TokenService>();
            services.AddScoped<IPlantRepository, PlantRepository>();
            services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());

            return services;

        }
    }
}


The content of my BaseApiController.cs:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace API.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class BaseApiController: ControllerBase
    {

    }
}

The content of my PlantsController.cs:
using API.Data;
using API.Entities;
using API.Interfaces;
using AutoMapper;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace API.Controllers;

public class PlantsController: BaseApiController
{
    private readonly IPlantRepository _plantRepository;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    // Plant controller constructor
    public PlantsController(IPlantRepository plantRepository, IMapper mapper)
    {
       _mapper = mapper;
       _plantRepository = plantRepository;
    }

    [HttpPost("search")] // /api/plants/search
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Plant>>> SearchPlants([FromBody] PlantSearchFormDto searchDto)
    {
        var results = await _plantRepository.GetPlantsBasedOnSearchFormContentAsync(searchDto);
        return Ok(results);
    }

    [HttpGet("{id}")] // /api/plants/1
    public async Task<ActionResult<Plant>> GetPlantByIdAsync(int id)
    {
        return await _plantRepository.GetPlantByIdAsync(id);
    
    }
}



Good morning,
I haven't had time to test your code yet, but I may have some ideas to help you.
As you say, your configuration seems correct, it may just be that you are not calling your endpoint correctly

Currently, what and how are you trying to call it?
--> You have defined an endpoint which has an HTTP POST verb with a DTO in body, check that you are sending a valid body in HTTP POST.

Have you tried adding a swagger?
--> This could allow you to see if your endpoint is accessible and if it is the right route.

CORS are often a tricky affair as they block depending on where your call is coming from... Try playing with the CORS settings or disabling/allowing all to see if that's the problem.


If none of these suggestions work, I'll let you share in more detail how to query your endpoint (via Postman or other, the body you send, etc.)
Good day,
Benito

HI Benito,
Thank you for your comment. Thanks to your suggestions, I found the problem. Instead of listening on https://plantguide.ch/api/plants/4 somehow the controller is listening to https://plantguide.ch/api/api/plants/4. However, I do not understand yet where the "double api" is coming from but at least it works! Thanks a lot! I will delve into my code to look for the "double api" source.
Have a great evening, Philipp

I guess I found the issue. I am hosting my API in a sub application called api which is hosted in IIS under https://plantguide.ch/api. Because I had the controller specified as [Route("api/[controller]")] that then became https://plantguide.ch/api/api/[controller]. But now it doesn't work anymore for my local development environment because on localhost it is listening now to https://localhost:5001/Plants/4.
